# ASP.NET VB DropdownList

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

Simple problem.

I have a dropdownlist and I want to set it's value on page_load.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="SubmissionTypeDD" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

I fill this dropdown using some database values, currently 22, 17 and 44

Now I want this dropdown's selected value on page_load to be "17"

```
SubmissionTypeDD.SelectedValue = "17"
```

This does not work, it defaults to the top value regardless.

I have tried putting this in "If IsPostBack = False Then" but no success.

This is the code I use to fill the DD:

```
Dim readIntoTable As New SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT submissionTypes FROM dbo.submissionTypes ORDER    BY submissionTypes ASC", conn)
conn.Open()

SubmissionTypeDD.DataSource = readIntoTable.ExecuteReader
SubmissionTypeDD.DataTextField = "submissionTypes"
SubmissionTypeDD.DataBind()

conn.Close()
```

Cheers!

Comment: Can you show the code of how your filling the dropdownlist?

Comment: Added the code for the DD

Comment: Where is the code to fill the DD?

Comment: It's in my original question above...

Comment: Sorry, I phrased that badly. Where is the DD code fired? Page_Load?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: So, just to confirm, in the Page_Load event you fill your DD first using the code you've supplied, then after that you type SubmissionTypeDD.SelectedValue = "17"?

Comment: I load the DD in page_load. Then I want to set the dd.selectedValue by getting the value from the Database. I'm not manually entering the value, I was using "17" in my post as an example! This what I am doing: submissionTypeDD.SelectedValue = dr.GetValue(3)

Comment: Ok, so have you debugged to see what you're actually getting back from dr.GetValue(3)? This will need to be a string value as well or converted to one.

Comment: Yeah it is the right value from the DB. I have applied .ToString() to it as well

Comment: Have you tried using FindByValue or FindByText?

Comment: Solved! Sorry to waste everyone's time. The values I had set in the Database had trailing whitespace which I had not trimmed, so it was actually something like "77&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" rather than "77".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to waste everyone's time. The values I had set in the Database had trailing whitespace which I had not trimmed, so it was actually something like "77   " rather than "77"

Answer (score 0):

Do it in the `PreRenderComplete` event, instead of the page `Load` event. Databinding doesn't normally happen until *after* the Load the event, and so binding the values from your database to the drop down was replacing your `SelectedValue` choice. If you do it on PreRender instead, the data binding is already finished, and the choice will stick.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178472.aspx):

> **PreRenderComplete**
>
> Raised after each data bound control whose DataSourceID property is set calls its DataBind method. For more information, see Data Binding Events for Data-Bound Controls later in this topic.

Also, something is starting to smell for me with this whole design. Either the items from the DB are dynamic or they aren't. If they are dynamic, how do you know to use "17"? You're likely better off adding a column to the table where you can indicate the default, and just order the results so that the default is at the top or use other code to force it to be selected based on that column. If the items aren't dynamic, why bother with the DB at all? Just hard-code the whole list. I know data-driven sounds better, but it's also a performance drain, and YAGNI.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything either unfortunately.

Comment: @levis84 My mistake: I just check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178472.aspx), and that should have been `PreRenderComplete`. PreRender also happens immediately before data binding. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a ListItem and set Selected to True

```
Dim liValue As ListItem = SubmissionTypeDD.Items.FindByValue("17")
If (liValue IsNot Nothing) Then
   liValue.Selected = True
 End If
```

Comment: I don't think this is the solution as I am getting the data from the DB so it is therefore dynamic.

Comment: Just replace "17" with the value from your DB.

Comment: Something is starting to smell for me with this whole design in the OP. Either the items from the DB are dynamic, or they aren't. If they are dynamic, how do you know to use "17"? If they aren't, why bother with the DB?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yes, I'm starting to wonder if they know enough about ASP.NET to implement our recommendations.

Comment: Included that as part of my answer now.

Comment: I have added the databind dropdown code. I am using the database to fill the dropdown. I typed "17" as an example, sorry should have been more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting the selectedValue property AFTER any databinding that occurs on the dropdown list. If you set the selectedValue property before a databind, then that will be overwritten with the new databind.

If you're unsure how to properly populate your dropdown list, refer to this excellent answer: 
[Databind a dropdownlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292735/databind-a-dropdownlist)