# How to call a list thats made from an enum and bind it to a drop down list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, enums

So I have a class file with:

```
    public enum Size
    {
        Large = 1,
        Medium = 2,
        Small = 3
    }

    public static class Serv
    {


        public static List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> GetSize()
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> _size = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();

            foreach (var enm in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Size)))
            {
                _size.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>((int)enm, ((Size)enm).ToString()));
            }

            return _size;
        }
     }
```

Then I have my main page with a drop down list:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddlSize.Items.Add(GetSize);
    }
```

But this doesn't work since in the Page_Load GetSize doesn't exist in the current context. I have referenced the file. So how do I go about populating my drop down list with my list GetSize()

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: How are you adding method do items?

Comment: by doesn't work, I mean GetSize does not exist in the current context. And yes I have referenced it in the header.

Comment: Maybe you should call it properly? ddlSize.Items.Add(TerritoryServices.GetSize());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [DataBind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292735/databind-a-dropdownlist) the results of your method to the DropDownList

```
ddlSize.DataSource = TerritoryServices.GetSize();
ddlSize.DataTextField = "Value";
ddlSize.DataValueField = "Key";
ddlSize.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2):

I see two things:

1) you are adding a method to your list rather than the *results* of that method:

2) Your method returns a `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>`, which is fine, but you add those objects *directly* to your drop-down list, which will not show the results I think you're expecting.

I would add the items individually, using the overload that accepts a key and a vlue:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp in GetSize())
    {
      ddlSize.Items.Add(New ListItem(kvp.Value.ToString(), kvp.Key.ToString()) ;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I kind of see what you're getting at. But BCdotNets answer worked exactly how I needed it. I shall give your way a go though. Thanks.

Comment: Data binding works as well.  Glad it worked for you.