# Why does binding a DropDownList function differently than manually adding ListItems?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

**Snippet One**

I add list items to my drop down one at a time.

```
var ddlHour = new DropDownList {ID = "ddlHour" + i};
ddlHour.Items.Add(new ListItem("12 AM", "0:00"));
ddlHour.Items.Add(new ListItem("1 AM", "1:00"));
ddlHour.Items.Add(new ListItem("2 AM", "2:00"));
Console.WriteLine(ddlHour.Items[0].Value); 
// Prints 0:00
```

**Snippet Two**

I bind my drop down to an array of list items.

```
var hourItems = new[]
{
    new ListItem("12 AM", "0:00"), // "Text", "Value"
    new ListItem("1 AM", "1:00"),
    new ListItem("2 AM", "2:00")
};
var ddlHour = new DropDownList {ID = "ddlHour" + i, DataSource = hourItems};
ddlHour.DataBind();
Console.WriteLine(ddlHour.Items[0].Value); 
// Prints 12 AM
```

After the first snippet executes, I inspect the values of each item and find `"0:00"`, `"1:00"`, and `"2:00"`. Exactly what I expect.

After the second snippet executes, I inspect the values of each item and find `"12 AM"`, `"1 AM"`, and `"2 AM"`. Not what I expect. What happened to my values?

Comment: OK, have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292735/databind-a-dropdownlist

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I was in the middle of writing an answer based on your finding and Win beat me to it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are same. Only different is that if you use **DataSource**, you need to specify **[DataTextField](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** and **[DataValueField](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**.

```
...
ddlHour.DataBind();
ddlHour.DataTextField = "Text";
ddlHour.DataValueField = "Value";
Console.WriteLine(ddlHour.Items[0].Value);
```

Comment: I am surprised that the default value for `DataValueField` is not `"Value"`. I am also surprised that it knew how to bind the Text field, but not the Value field. That seems inconsistent. I appreciate the sources and the correct answer.

Comment: It sure doesn't make sense.   The documentation for ListItem describes text and value: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f7h2h8h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx