# Get nodes from asmx service that return string XML, C#

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, web-services, soap

I am trying to query a public web service that returns the following xml:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<string xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
<NewDataSet> <Table> <Country>Maldives</Country> <City>Gan</City> </Table> <Table> <Country>Maldives</Country> <City>Male</City> </Table> </NewDataSet>
</string>
```

How can I get the list of cities in c# for loading a dropdowlist?

This is my code:

```
var restClient = new RestClient("http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetCitiesByCountry");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        // request.Resource = "{version}/token";
        request.AddParameter("CountryName", "Maldives");


        var response = restClient.Execute(request);
```

//response.Content contains the troublesome string

I would appreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your XML consists of the output of [`DataSet.WriteXml(writer, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx8h06sz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) wrapped in a root element named `"{http://www.webserviceX.NET}string"`.  So it will be easiest to deserialize the inner XML as a [`DataSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then bind the appropriate column of the appropriate [`DataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx):

First, deserialize the set:

```
        var rootElement = XElement.Parse(xmlString); // xmlString is //response.Content

        var set = new DataSet();
        var setElement = rootElement.DescendantsAndSelf().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "NewDataSet").FirstOrDefault();
        if (setElement != null)
        {
            using (var reader = setElement.CreateReader())
            {
                set.ReadXml(reader, XmlReadMode.Auto);
            }
        }
```

Next, pick out a table with a column named `"City"`:

```
        var table = set.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Columns["City"] != null);
```

Now that you have a `DataTable`, you can bind it following the instructions in [What is the right way to populate a DropDownList from a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227510/what-is-the-right-way-to-populate-a-dropdownlist-from-a-database), [DropdownList DataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105265/dropdownlist-datasource) and/or [Databind a dropdownlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292735/databind-a-dropdownlist) using `DataTextField = "City"`.