# Display values from database (variable) to drop down in ASP

Tags: asp.net

I am working with ASP page where I receive the values from a stored procedure to variable properly, but I am not sure how to assign values to drop down.

I used the same way for the text box and it works fine.

In code below I am assigning values from data set to variable

```
cc_db_SiteSurveyOnly=bbInfoRs("SiteSurveyOnly").Value
```

And here is a code for the the HTML

```
            <select name="cc_LocalSiteSiteSurveyOnly" VALUE="<%=cc_db_SiteSurveyOnly%>">
               <option value="">Select</option>
               <option value="Y">Y</option>
               <option value="N">N</option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dzka5sf(v=vs.71).aspx

And populate with DataBinding. Here's a question already answered about that:

[Databind a dropdownlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292735/databind-a-dropdownlist)