# Can't set ASP.NET drop down list to return query value in a datatable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string, drop-down-menu

Ok so I have been searching for three days and so far I can not find an answer that explains what I need to do.

Here is what I need. I have an asp.net content page. On that page there are some drop down list boxes. I have a query that fetches data from a SQL DB and puts in a Data table and that is working fine.

What I am trying to do is set the text of the ddl to a string that has been returned from the query.

Here is the HTML side:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProbType" CssClass="ddlEdit" runat="server" Width="150px" DataSourceID="SdsProbType" DataTextField="probtype" DataValueField="probtype" />
```

Here is the VB code behind:

```
            If dt.Rows.Count > 1 Then
                stupidString = dt.Rows(RowCount)("probtype")
                ddlProbType.SelectedValue = stupidString
            Else
                stupidString = dt.Rows(RowCount)("probtype")
                ddlProbType.SelectedValue = stupidString
            End If
```

I have added the variable stupidString and the set a break point to check the value being returned and it is correct. When the next line executes the ddl does NOT get the text assigned. I can mouse over the variable stupidString and see that the value it was assigned from the query is correct.

When I have tried setting the ddl directly from the data table, I have tried  .ToSting() and .ToString.Trim() to the end of the dt.Rows line but it just will not assign!!

I know this probably something really stupid that I am not doing or overlooking but can anyone help? I do not want to assign a whole sql table to the ddl I just want to set the current list to the value that is returned by the sql query.

Comment: Forgot to put it in but this is the error I am getting:

Comment: (drop down list) has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items

Answer (score 0):

You need to [populate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14atsyf5(v=vs.85).aspx) the list first, e.g. by using

```
ddlProbType.Items.Add(New ListItem("Key","Value"))
```

or by using [Data Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292735/databind-a-dropdownlist).

After the list is populated, then you can tell the control which item should be selected.

Comment: That's just it. It IS already bound. i am simply trying to set the value to one of the list items to display on the page.

Comment: At what point does your code execute?  Bear in mind that [data binding happens after the PreRender event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#data_binding_events_for_databound_controls), so your code will have to run after that.  Or you can subscribe to the `DataBound` event.

Comment: i finally figured it out using the following:                     ddlProbType.Text = dt.Rows(RowCount)("probtype").ToString().Trim()